# How to get id of the row when sum of all previous rows exceeds a threshold mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table in mysql that is shown below

```
id             |    total_count 
-------------------------------
1              |   2
2              |  10
3              |  15
```

threshold is equal to 13
i want to get id of the row Where Sum of total_count is greater than 13
the query should return 3

Comment: This is a version of a running total query and the question isn't well articulated in my view.

Comment: What is **precise** MySQL version?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the lowest id where the running total is >= to the threshold and you have mysql 8 or above

```
DROP table if exists t;


create table t
(id int, total_count int);
insert into t values
(1              ,   2),
(2              ,  10),
(3              ,  15);

with cte as
(select t.*,
        sum(total_count) over (order by id) rt,
        threshold
from t
cross join (select 13 as threshold) s
),
 cte1 as
(select min(id) minid from cte where rt >=threshold)

select minid from cte1;

+-------+
| minid |
+-------+
|     3 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```